# Iframe and Page load issue

Tags: asp.net, html, css, iframe, pageload

My page have an iFrame here:

[image]

here is the code of putting the iframe:

```
<iframe src="" name="iframe_a" scrolling="no" width="100%" frameborder="0" style="margin-top: 200px; background-color: White;" 
    id="I1"></iframe>
```

when I click any button that triggers page load, the page keeps adding more white spaces below the iFrame:

[image]

How can i prevent this kind of problem? 
NOTE:(I'm using ASP.NET)
I will appreciate all answers, advices and suggestions :)

Comment: Could you provide any relevant code snippets?

Comment: Ok sir I will add the code in the question :)

Comment: The only code that is revelant in here is the putting of iframe, I know when you click any button in ASP.NET webforms, it will automatically load the page, but why it keeps creating white spaces below the iframe??

Comment: Try and observe the element tree change in something like chrome / firebug

Comment: No idea of what are you talking about sir, can you explain it more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "iFrame" is not at fault. Check the source of the "iFrame".